# How to rename the PivotTables in a for loop?

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, pivot, pivot-table

I would like to generate four different pivot tables in one excel sheet by using for loop. However, when I run my vba code, it shows that the name for that pivot table is already used. Then I think maybe I can generate a vector of names and then pick name from that vector each time as the name of a pivottable, but it does not work. I do this way:

```
For n = 0 To 3
    PivotTable_Name(n) = "PivotTable" & "n"
Next n
```

Also, if I only want to show one result of fieldpage 
Can any one help me to look at it? and give me any suggestion?

Here is my code.

```
    Dim rngData As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastCol As Long
    Dim pvtItm As PivotItem
    Dim ListFields(0 To 5) As String
    Dim PivotTable_Name(0 To 3) As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim k As Integer

    **For k = 0 To 3
        For n = 0 To 3
            PivotTable_Name(n) = "PivotTable" & "n"
        Next n

        wsPvtTbl.PivotTables.Add PivotCache:=PvtTblCache, TableDestination:=wsPvtTbl.Cells(3, 1 + 4 * k), TableName:=PivotTable_Name(k), DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion11
        Set PvtTbl = wsPvtTbl.PivotTables(PivotTable_Name(k))**

        PvtTbl.ManualUpdate = True

        For j = 0 To LastCol - 1
            ListFields(j) = wsData.Cells(1, j + 1)
        Next j

        'add row, column and page (report filter) fields:
        Set pvtFld = PvtTbl.PivotFields(ListFields(1))
        pvtFld.Orientation = xlPageField

        Set pvtFld = PvtTbl.PivotFields(ListFields(2))
        pvtFld.Orientation = xlRowField

        For i = 3 To LastCol - 1
            With PvtTbl.PivotFields(ListFields(i))
                .Orientation = xlDataField
                .Function = xlSum
                .NumberFormat = "#,##0"
                .Position = i - 2
            End With
        Next i                
        PvtTbl.ManualUpdate = False            
    Next k

End Sub
```

Comment: change `PivotTable_Name(n) = "PivotTable" & "n"` to `PivotTable_Name(n) = "PivotTable" & n` (take the `"` out of the `n`)

Comment: Thank you Shai~ That works now!